# Is there a way in ScrollMagic to make the setPin duration be equal to time instead of scroll distance?

Tags: gsap, scrollmagic

I have a tween that is triggered by scrolling to a specific section that pins, and then the animation plays. Right now it plays through on trigger, not tied to scroll, but the pin itself is set to scroll. So it plays the animation and you have to scroll like 500 pixels to unpin the section. Ideally, the pin would last for the duration of the tween, like 500ms instead of having to scroll pixels to unpin. Is this possible?

Here is the code for how it is set up currently:

```js
// // build scenes
    this.controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    let tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.fromTo(
      ".gradient_lord",
      0.5,
      { css: { transform: "translateY(100%)" } },
      { css: { transform: "translateY(0%)" } },
      "+=.7"
    );
    tl.fromTo(
      "header.header_headline",
      1,
      { css: { opacity: "0" } },
      { css: { opacity: "1" } },
      "-=.03"
    );

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "#TextContent",
      duration: "25%",
      triggerHook: 0,
    })
      // .addIndicators({
      //   colorTrigger: "red",
      //   colorStart: "red",
      //   colorEnd: "red",
      //   indent: 5,
      // })
      .setPin("#TextContent")
      // .setClassToggle("#GradDad", "hello")
      // .on("enter", this.sceneEnter)
      .setTween(tl)
      // .on("progress", function (event) {
      //   console.log("Scene progress changed to " + event.progress);
      // })
      .addTo(this.controller);

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "#TextContent",
      // duration: 800,
      triggerHook: 0,
    })
      // .addIndicators({
      //   colorTrigger: "red",
      //   colorStart: "red",
      //   colorEnd: "red",
      //   indent: 5,
      // })
      .setTween(tl)
      // .on("progress", function (event) {
      //   console.log("Scene progress changed to " + event.progress);
      // })
      .addTo(this.controller);
```

Comment: Hey Joshua. We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. We recommend the official GSAP plugin instead: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way. Additionally it seems you're using very old syntax. We highly recommend you [upgrade to GSAP 3 syntax](https://greensock.com/3-migration/). Also use xPercent and yPercent instead of setting transforms like that.

Comment: Thanks Zach, is what I'm describing above possible with ScrollTrigger? Having the pin last only the duration of the tween?

Comment: Yes it is! I recommend that you go through the links above, try to do it yourself, and if you can't figure it out then you create a [minimal demo](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/9002-read-this-first-how-to-create-a-codepen-demo/) and post to the [GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) if you get stuck.